# How can I use form data in Django directly as context in another view

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm having big trouble understanding the whole forms business in django. As I understand it the cleaned form data is a dictionary. So all my defined form fields should be in the dictionary like so: {'definedform': userinput, ...}. Is this correct?
I want to create a form in which a user can input data. This data should then be send to a different view, in which the inputted data is rendered with a latex template (and subsequently rendered into a pdf). This works more or less fine if I define the context in the /create_pdf/ view and grab the user input manually. But I suppose there is a nicer way. What I think should work:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        persoform = PersonalForm(request.POST, prefix='personal')
        if persoform.is_valid():
            content = persoform.cleaned_data()
            content = Context(content)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/create_pdf/')
    else:
        persoform = PersonalForm()
    return render(request, 'app/template.html', {'persoform': persoform})
```

And in my /create_pdf/ view:

```
def create_pdf(request):
    template = get_template('app/latextemplate.tex')
    rendered_tpl = template.render(content)
    [...]
```

So, how can I make sure, to pass the data from my index view to my create_pdf view?

EDIT:

Forgot to mention: The error is "'content' not defined". So I understand that the /create_pdf/ view doesn't get content dictionary, but I have no idea how I would make sure that it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the data in to the session on submit, and pop it out in the second view.

```
if form.is_valid():
    request.session['perso'] = form.cleaned_data
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/create_pdf/')
```

...

```
def create_pdf(request):
        data = request.session.pop('perso'], {})
```

Comment: Unfortunately the data seems to be empty. At least I get redirected to my /create_pdf/ view, but the rendered PDF is empty. I tried to find some bugs in my index view and funnily, if I add a print statement after the "if request == POST" OR after "if form.valid" it doesn't get printed... so something else seems to be wrong. How come that the POST request isn't recognized properly?

Comment: It didn't work, because the form's action in my html template was set to "/create_pdf/"... i now set it to "." and it worked. Do you have an idea how the form action should be set in general, the official Django Tutorial is a bit vague on this one, in my opinion.

Comment: Remove the `]` on perso key: `'perso']` by `'perso'`.